# How convert many AsyncTasks to Rx Observables in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-asynctask, kotlin, rx-android

I'm using Facebook Graph API to find users that liked my posts. All logic implements in few steps:

1. Find all posts by making request to API in AsyncTask
2. Convert this AT to Rx.Observable
3. Map Observables GraphResponse to List(Post is POJO)
4. Call FlatMap operator and in it body call method that iterate each post and make asyncTask, then convert it into Observable and put in Array.
5. Merge Array of Observables in One Observable.
6. Map its GraphResponse to Liked Profile
7. Subscribe and render Likers List
8. PROFIT!

And I have some little problem at step #4-5. Please, look at method 'likes' in repository. In comments i wrote problems

**Hint**: I'm using MVP + Clean Architecture with Repository(data layer) and Interactor(business layer)

```
class FacebookRepository {

    private val facebook = Facebook.instance()
    private val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

    fun posts(): Observable<GraphResponse>? {

        return RxDecorator<GraphResponse>().decorate(Observable.defer({
            val request = GraphRequest(
                    facebook.token,
                    "/me/posts",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    GraphRequest.Callback { /* handle the result */ }
            )

            Observable.just(request.executeAndWait())
        }))

    }

    fun setFaceBookAccessToken(currentAccessToken: AccessToken?) {
        facebook.token = currentAccessToken
    }

    fun logout() {
        facebook.logout()
    }

    fun token(): String? {
        return facebook.token?.token
    }

    fun likes(posts: List<Post>?): Observable<List<Profile>> {

        Log.d("observables:posts", posts.toString())

        val p = iterateObservables(posts) // STOP HERE and WAIT to complete this method.

        // Then p is composite - merge and return
        return Observable.merge(p).map {
            Log.d("merge:posts", it.toString())
            val profiles = gson.fromJson<List<Profile>>(
                    it.jsonObject["data"].toString(),
                    object : TypeToken<List<Profile>>() {}.type
            )

            return@map profiles
        }
    }

    private fun iterateObservables(posts: List<Post>?): MutableList<Observable<GraphResponse>>? {
        val observables: MutableList<Observable<GraphResponse>>? = null

        Log.d("iterateObs:posts", posts.toString())
        Log.d("posts_not_null", (posts != null).toString())
        Log.d("posts.size", posts?.size.toString())

        if (posts != null) {
            for (post in posts) {

                Log.d("iterateObs:post", post.toString())

                val request = GraphRequest(
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            "/${post.id}/likes",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            GraphRequest.Callback { Log.d("fb:post:id", "${post.id}: ${it.jsonObject}")
                        }).executeAsync()

                Log.d("obs:after:post", observables.toString())
            }
        }

        return observables
    }
}
```

And this is Interactor

```
class FacebookInteractor {

    private val callbackManager = com.facebook.CallbackManager.Factory.create()
    private val repository = FacebookRepository()

    fun facebookAuth(view: IMainView) {
        LoginManager
                .getInstance()
                .logInWithReadPermissions(
                        view.getContext() as MainActivity,
                        Arrays.asList("user_friends", "user_likes", "user_posts", "public_profile", "email")
                )
    }

    fun onFacebookLoginResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    fun facebookAccessTokenChanged(oldAccessToken: AccessToken?, currentAccessToken: AccessToken?) {
        if(oldAccessToken?.token != currentAccessToken?.token) {
            repository.setFaceBookAccessToken(currentAccessToken)
        }
    }

    fun likes(): Observable<List<Profile>>? {
        return repository.posts()?.map {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val posts = gson.fromJson<List<Post>>(
                    it.jsonObject["data"].toString(),
                    object : TypeToken<List<Post>>() {}.getType()
            )

            return@map posts
        }?.flatMap {
            return@flatMap repository.likes(it)
        }
    }

    fun logout() {
        repository.logout()
    }

    fun isLogined(): Boolean {
        return repository.token() != null
    }

}
```

I'm Using Kotlin as development language.

Comment: What is the problem? Why does not your code satisfy you? Please state that in the question.

Comment: Please, look at method 'likes' in repository. In comments i wrote problems

Comment: Do you want to stop the executing of that method until the response arrives? You can use Future to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks EveryOne!) But answer was in another case) Problem was in logic, not in implementation) Facebook SDK has [RequestBatch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) And no need in Future or stoping Threads)

```
package com.github.scrobot.likes_listener.data.facebook

import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.*
import com.github.scrobot.likes_listener.data.facebook.models.Facebook
import com.github.scrobot.likes_listener.data.facebook.models.Post
import com.github.scrobot.likes_listener.data.facebook.models.Profile
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import rus.pifpaf.client.util.rx.RxDecorator
import rx.Observable
import java.util.*


/**
 * Created by aleksejskrobot on 07.12.16.
 */
class FacebookRepository {

    private val facebook = Facebook.instance()
    private val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

    fun posts(): Observable<GraphResponse>? {

        return RxDecorator<GraphResponse>().decorate(Observable.defer({
            val request = GraphRequest(
                    facebook.token,
                    "/me/posts",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    GraphRequest.Callback { /* handle the result */ }
            )

            Observable.just(request.executeAndWait())
        }))

    }

    fun setFaceBookAccessToken(currentAccessToken: AccessToken?) {
        facebook.token = currentAccessToken
    }

    fun logout() {
        facebook.logout()
    }

    fun token(): String? {
        return facebook.token?.token
    }

    fun likes(posts: List<Post>?): Observable<List<Profile>> {

        val batch = GraphRequestBatch()

        posts?.mapTo(batch) { post ->
            GraphRequest(
                    facebook.token,
                    "/${post.id}/likes",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    GraphRequest.Callback { Log.d("fb:post:id", "${post.id}: ${it.jsonObject}") }
            )
        }

        return RxDecorator<List<GraphResponse>>().decorate(rx.Observable.defer({
            rx.Observable.just(batch.executeAndWait())
        })).map {
            Log.d("batchResponse:it", it.toString())

            val list = ArrayList<Profile>()

            for (i in it) {
                list.addAll(gson.fromJson<List<Profile>>(
                        i.jsonObject["data"].toString(),
                        object : TypeToken<List<Profile>>() {}.type
                ))
            }

            list.filter {
                list.contains(it)
            }

            return@map list
        }
    }
}
```